# Show the Marker title, as soon as the mapbox map is loaded on android

Tags: java, android, google-maps, mapbox, marker

I would like to show to user the title of the marker added to a map, however none of the solutions that i've found on the web is giving anything. Unfortunately not the showInfoWindow nor selectMarker helps:(

Please see below my code:

```
public class DetailAnimalPlantMapFragment extends Fragment implements OnMapReadyCallback, PermissionsListener {

private MapView mapView;
private MapboxMap mapboxMapMyLocation;
PermissionsManager permissionsManager;
List<Point> positions;
LatLng[] latLng;
LatLng myLocation;

@Override
public void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    Mapbox.getInstance(getActivity(), getString(R.string.map_box_api));
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_ustka_object_map_mapbox, container,
            false);
    mapView = rootView.findViewById(R.id.mapViewMapBox);

    Bundle bundle = getArguments();
    Nature nature = (Nature) bundle.getSerializable("nature");

    final double lat = nature.getLat();
    final double lng = nature.getLng();
    final String name = nature.getName();

    mapView.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    mapView.getMapAsync(new OnMapReadyCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onMapReady(MapboxMap mapboxMap) {

            if(!nature.getWaypoints().isEmpty()){

                positions = PolylineUtils.decode(nature.getWaypoints(),5);

                latLng = new LatLng[positions.size()];
                for (int i = 0; i < positions.size(); i++) {
                    latLng[i] = new LatLng(
                            positions.get(i).latitude(),
                            positions.get(i).longitude());
                }

                mapboxMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                        .setPosition(new LatLng(latLng[0]
                                .getLatitude(),latLng[0]
                                .getLongitude()))
                        .setTitle("Początek"));

                mapboxMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                        .setPosition(new LatLng(latLng[latLng.length-1]
                                .getLatitude(),latLng[latLng.length-1]
                                .getLongitude()))
                        .setTitle("Koniec"));

                mapboxMap.addPolyline(new PolylineOptions()
                        .add(latLng)
                        .color(Color.parseColor("#38afea"))
                        .width(5));
            }

            mapboxMapMyLocation = mapboxMap;
            enableLocationPlugin();

            CameraPosition position = new CameraPosition.Builder()
                    .target(new LatLng(lat,lng))
                    .zoom(11)
                    .tilt(30)
                    .build();
            mapboxMapMyLocation.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory
                    .newCameraPosition(position), 4000);
            Marker marker = mapboxMapMyLocation.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().setPosition(new LatLng(lat,lng))
                    .setTitle(name));

            mapboxMapMyLocation.selectMarker(marker);

            /*marker.showInfoWindow(mapboxMapMyLocation,mapView);*/
        }
    });
    return rootView;
}

@Override
@SuppressWarnings( {"MissingPermission"})
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    mapView.onStart();
}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    mapView.onResume();
}

@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    mapView.onPause();
}

@Override
public void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    mapView.onStop();
}

@Override
public void onLowMemory() {
    super.onLowMemory();
    mapView.onLowMemory();
}

@Override
public void onDestroyView() {
    super.onDestroyView();
    mapView.onDestroy();
}

@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    mapView.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
}

@Override
public void onMapReady(MapboxMap mapboxMap) {
    DetailAnimalPlantMapFragment.this.mapboxMapMyLocation = mapboxMap;
    enableLocationPlugin();
}

@SuppressWarnings( {"MissingPermission"})
private void enableLocationPlugin() {
    // Check if permissions are enabled and if not request
    if (PermissionsManager.areLocationPermissionsGranted(getActivity())) {

        LocationLayerPlugin locationLayerPlugin = new LocationLayerPlugin(mapView, mapboxMapMyLocation);

        // Set the plugin's camera mode

        Location location = locationLayerPlugin.getLastKnownLocation();
        myLocation = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(),location.getLongitude());
        locationLayerPlugin.setCameraMode(CameraMode.TRACKING_GPS);
        getLifecycle().addObserver(locationLayerPlugin);
    } else {
        permissionsManager = new PermissionsManager(this);
        permissionsManager.requestLocationPermissions(getActivity());
    }
}

@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions, int[] grantResults) {
}

@Override
public void onExplanationNeeded(List<String> permissionsToExplain) {
}

@Override
public void onPermissionResult(boolean granted) {
}
```

}

As you can see I'm opening the mapView in a fragment, poiting to both the user's location and the object's location.

Comment: "showInfoWindow() nor selectMarker() helps" is indeed abnormal

Comment: Could it be because I start the map in fragment?

Comment: Please post more code: lifecycle methods, and where you used `showInfoWindow()`.

Comment: I have no issues selecting a `Marker` that's just added to the map. Could you retest with calling the `MapView#onCreate` from your fragment's `onViewCreated`? Because that's the correct setup.